# Bizarre Behavior of randomForest Package When Dropping One Prediction Class

Tags: r, machine-learning, classification, random-forest

I am running a random forest model that produces results that make absolutely no sense to me from a statistical perspective, and thus I'm convinced that something *must* be going wrong code-wise with the randomForest package.

The predicted / left hand side variable is, in at least this iteration of the model, a party ID with 3 possible outcomes: Democrat, Independent, Republican. I run the model, get results, fine. I'm at this point not super concerned with the results per se, but rather what happens when I make a small modification.

I then try to run it excluding Independents, and that's when things go awry in ways I find mystifying. Specifically, it loses almost all ability to predict *anything*, and labels almost *all* observations as belonging to the same class (Democrats).

"OK, fine, the information contained in the Independent observations was important to prediction." This was my first thought, although I couldn't for the life of me figure out why that would be true since the model is very bad at identifying independents.

Weirdly, a simple test of that hypothesis proved that it is **not** true. If I drop all but one observation with a party ID of Independent (sample size is a little over 4000 observations total, so 1 observation is a rounding error), the model performs fine. Thus, even when it is for all intents and purposes learning absolutely nothing from the "Independent" outcome category, the model runs as expected. It's only once the Independent category is actually removed that things go wrong.

Also, just to head off a potential suggestion: it does not appear to somehow be a result of the creation of a new LHS variable. If I instead just droplevels on party_id_3_cat after removing independents and use the same LHS variable, it leads to the same results.

The results of the "no independents" version (called "two_cat" below) and "only one independent" version ("leave_one" below) should, as far as I can imagine, be nearly identical because they have nearly identical data. And yet the actual results produced by the two models are **dramatically** different. I've racked my brain and can't imagine why this would be true. Does anyone know anything about the randomForest package (or about random forest models in general, although that seems less likely) that could explain this behavior? If it's important, both the LHS and RHS variables are factor variables.

Thanks in advance!

Code:

```
load("three_cat.Rda")
two_cat<-subset(three_cat,party_id_3_cat!="2. Independents")
leave_one_in<-subset(three_cat,party_id_3_cat!="2.     Independents"|case_id=="30")
two_cat$party_id_2_cat<-as.factor(ifelse(two_cat$party_id_3_cat=="1. Democrats (including leaners)","Dem","Rep"))

rf_three_cat  <-        randomForest(party_id_3_cat~[RHS VARS},
                        data=three_cat,
                        ntree=200,mtry=4,
                        type="classification",
                        importance=TRUE,confusion=TRUE)
rf_leave_one  <-randomForest(party_id_3_cat~[RHS VARS],
                         data=leave_one_in,
                         ntree=200,mtry=4,
                         type="classification",
                         importance=TRUE,confusion=TRUE)
rf_two_cat    <-randomForest(party_id_2_cat~[RHS VARS],
                         data=two_cat,
                         ntree=200,mtry=4,
                         type="classification",
                         importance=TRUE,confusion=TRUE)

rf_three_cat$confusion
rf_leave_one$confusion
rf_two_cat$confusion
```

Results:

```
> rf_three_cat$confusion
                                   1. Democrats (including leaners) 2. Independents 3. Republicans (including leaners) class.error
1. Democrats (including leaners)                               1150               3                                668   0.3684789
2. Independents                                                 296               4                                231   0.9924670
3. Republicans (including leaners)                              600               9                               1055   0.3773234

> rf_leave_one$confusion
                                   1. Democrats (including leaners) 2. Independents 3. Republicans (including leaners) class.error
1. Democrats (including leaners)                               1080               0                                741   0.4069193
2. Independents                                                   0               0                                  1   1.0000000
3. Republicans (including leaners)                              517               0                               1097   0.3203222

> rf_two_cat$confusion
     Dem Rep class.error
Dem 1776  45   0.0247117
Rep 1581  33   0.9795539
```

Comment: How are you determining that removing independents causes all responses to become Democrat?  I don't see anything in your question which supports that.  My suspicion that you are interpreting your forest model incorrectly.

Comment: Look at the predictions generated by each model in the confusion matrices.

Comment: More specifically, the models "rf_leave_one" and "rf_two_cat" have identical data and identical RHS variables with one tiny exception: the former has one addition observation, which has party ID "2. Independents."

And yet the former model classifies 46.5% of their shared observations as "1. Democrats (including leaners)" while the latter classifies 97.7% of the observations that way.

Statistically, shouldn't it be nearly impossible to obtain these results merely by removing a single observation?

Comment: Yes, I would have imagined that having just one independent would not change things much from having zero independents.  But, if your forest model is picking up on it, then it could explain your observations.  Actually, the Republican/Democrat split looks very similar with one independent and _all_ independents.

Comment: There is another issue here.  You need to first verify that your model, with all data, has any statistical significance.  If it's a weak model, then discussing what happens with zero, one, or all independents is a somewhat moot point.

Comment: Tim Biegeleisen has a point, these models appear quite weak, perhaps you should consider tuning the `mtry` and `ntree` hyper parameters by using balanced accuracy or another similar measure and then comparing the models. The one observation thing is quite interesting, if you are interested in posting the data I'd give it a look.